# What is the `tuneLength` parameter in `caret`'s `train` function for tuning a conditional inference tree model?

Tags: r, performance, parameters, caret, ctree

I'm trying to apply the `caret` package to my conditional inference tree model, as I need to tune the parameters for said model.  I can see what the other options for the `train` function refer to, but I was wondering, what is `tuneLength` ?

I have tried to apply the k-fold cross validation tuning method to achieve the best parameters for my model, but I can't understand what the option `tuneLength` in the `train` function for the `caret` package refers to. Is it some parameter which should be fixed, or how is it calculated?

Thank you in advance.